# find the longest match of a string in list c#

Tags: c#

I have a list of string I need to find the longest match of my search string in the list.

for example the list contains :  "test", "abc", "testing", "testingap" and my search string is  'testingapplication'

the result should be 'testingap'

here is what I did so far , it does the work but I'm looking is there any better efficient way to do this

```
string search= "testingapplication";
List<string> names = new List<string>(new[] { "test", "abc", "testing", "testingap" });
List<string> matchedItems = new List<string>();

foreach (string item in names)
{
        if (search.Contains(item))
        {
            matchedItems.Add(item);
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        } 
}

var WordMatch= matchedItems.Aggregate("", (max, cur) => max.Length > cur.Length ? max : cur);
Console.WriteLine("WordMatch"+WordMatch);
```

Comment: **How** is it 'not working'?

Comment: it is working,I'm looking for a better way to get the same result

Answer (score 10):

Since you are already using LINQ, you could consider ordering your "names" by length via the [`OrderByDescending()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534855(v=vs.110).aspx) method and grab the first that contains your string using [`FirstOrDefault()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx) as seen below:

```
var match = names.OrderByDescending(n => n.Length)
                 .FirstOrDefault(n => search.Contains(n));

if (match == null)
{
    // No match was found, handle accordingly.
}
else
{
    // match will contain your longest string
}
```

Comment: since linq is actually very slow I tried using regex but it only return the first match,even regex.Matches that suppose to return a collection of matches it didn't, here is what I did so far

Comment: var regex = new Regex(string.Join("|", names), RegexOptions.Compiled);
 for (var match = regex.Match(search); match.Success; match = match.NextMatch())
                      Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
                  MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(phoneNumber);
                  foreach (Match matche in matches)
                  {
                      GroupCollection groupCollection = matche.Groups;
                      Console.WriteLine(matche);
                  }

Comment: It's worth considering what type of performance you are looking for. LINQ is faster than you might think, especially when your search terms are already in memory (as is your case). Additionally regular expressions aren't always the fastest themselves, especially if you are going through the cost of compiling them each time (and ensuring that you are actually generating a decent one if doing so dynamically). Finally, consider _readability_ which I'll say that LINQ will generally beat the tar of out regular expressions any day of the week.